# how to check the response status in component.ts to call another service in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am catching the status code in my service from below code:

```
add(new: Add): Observable<Response> {
  return this.http
   .post(this.addURL, new , httpOptions)
     .map((response: Response) => {
      if (response) {
       if (response.status === 200) {
        return [{ status: response.status, response: <Response>response.json() }]
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Here is my component.ts code where I want to call the list after successful add

```
  addDetails(): void {
var new = this.form.value.array;
new = JSON.stringify(this.form.value.array);
this.addService.add(new)
  .subscribe(
  resultArray => this.Response = resultArray,
  error => console.log("Error :: " + error),    
  )
  if(Response.status ===200){
    this.getList();   
  }}
```

but I am getting the below error:
**Property 'status' does not exist on type 'typeof Response'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to return Object instead of Array:

```
return { status: response.status, response: <Response>response.json() }
```

When you access Array item, you have to use index of the item.
So in your case, when you want to get the status code, you do this **into subscribe method**:

```
this.addService.add(_new)
  .subscribe(
  resultArray => {
    this.Response = resultArray
    if(resultArray[0].status ===200){
      this.getList();   
    }
  },
  error => console.log("Error :: " + error))
```

**Note:** Don't forget that subscribe use asynchrone method. You can never access on the response it return outside.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get your status from `Response` CLASS, not the instance of it. Watch for the uppercase and your `typeof Response` part of error.

I think `if (resultArray[0].status === 200)` should work, though I don't understand why you're returning an array, so it could be `if (result.status === 200)`